# Tick Off With Random Start

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, underscore.js

I want to create a tick off rotation of integer.

For example I have list of number in array:

```
let array = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
]
```

Then find a random start.

For example

```
let random_start = 4
```

now the tickoff result should be:

```
console.log(this.tickoff(array,random_start))
```

> // 4,5,6,7,1,2,3

Comment: What is that random_start ? is it `index` or `element` of the array ?

Comment: either of 2 is acceptable  but .. element is much appreciated ..  :)

Comment: Yeah, gave answer to the both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work fine.

```js
function tickOff(array, random)
{
    var result = array.splice(random,array.length-random);
    return result.concat(array);
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length), value = array[index];
console.log("Tick off with random index : "+index+" Result : "+tickOff(array, index).join(","));

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var value = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)+1, index = array.indexOf(value);
console.log("Tick off with random value : "+value+" Result : "+tickOff(array, index).join(","));
```

Comment: :O hmm  this is so clean . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If `random_start` is the value you want to start with:

```js
array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
random_start = 4;

function tickoff(arr, startValue) {
  indexOf = arr.indexOf(startValue);
  str = "";
  if (indexOf == -1) {
    return str;
  }
  i = indexOf;
  while (i != indexOf - 1) {
    if (i >= arr.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    str += arr[i] + ",";
    i++;
  }
  str += arr[i];
  return str;
}

console.log(tickoff(array, random_start));
```

If `random_start` is the element (starting from 1) you want to start with:

```js
array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8];
random_start = 4;

function tickoff(arr, startElem) {
  str = "";
  if (startElem < 1 || startElem > arr.length) {
    return str;
  }
  i = startElem - 1;
  while (i != startElem - 2) {
    if (i >= arr.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    str += arr[i] + ",";
    i++;
  }
  str += arr[i];
  return str;
}

console.log(tickoff(array, random_start));
```

Comment: Wow .. :)  so fast .. Thank you every much!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
let array = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
]
let newArray=[];
let random_start = 3;
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++, random_start++){
  if(random_start==array.length){
      random_start=0;
  }
  newArray.push(array[random_start]);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: hmmm what is j =3 and t= 3 ?

Comment: here t is random_start and j is another variable. I can remove single variable.

Comment: so  the random_start and the j must be the same value as always ?

Comment: yes. I think you are confused. Okay now I am removing the second parameter.